# Multi dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, json

I am really struggling with arrays in general but I can't seem to do anything with this: https://www.easycron.com/document/list

I want to be able to access each "field". For example the [cron_job_name] for [2]. So in that example the result I'd be looking for is "Send newsletters".

I have been messing around all night long but I think the thing I am not getting past is that it has the  [status] => success [cron_jobs] => Array at the top.

So far the code I have is this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.easycron.com/rest/list?token=[MY     KEY]&sortby=cronId&order=desc");
$myArray = json_decode($json,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

All this really does though is gets me a copy of what is on that page.

Comment: `foreach ($myArray['cron_jobs'] as $cron_job) { print_r($cron_job); }` -- start with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able to print_r the array response, then you can cycle

```
if($myArray['status'] ==='success') {
   $crons = $myArray['cron_jobs'];
   foreach($crons as $cron){
     if($cron['cron_job_name'] == 'Send newsletters') {
        // Do your proccessing
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it!!! Thank you so much. now I just add a <? echo ($crons[1][url]); ?> for example and it gives me the right value !!! Superstar tanks a lot.

Comment: Ok! Remember to put your non numeric keys between ''.